# React Place Headers in Seperate file

Tags: reactjs, rxjs, react-router

I am importing the following header files in many files. Can I place them in a single file and import that file instead of importing all these headers again and again? Is it possible in React?

**Example**

```
    import { data } from "./store";
    import styles from "./css/style.css";
    import { constants } from "../../configurations";
    import { Title, Loader, Encode} from "../Components";
```

Can I do something like this?

Header.js

```
    import { data } from "./store";
    import styles from "./css/style.css";
    import { constants } from "../../configurations";
    import { Title, Loader, Encode} from "../Components";
```

And then only import "Header.js" instead of importing all the above links again?

Comment: couldn't you simply try it?

Comment: I tried it, it doesn't work. That's why I asked question maybe there is some way to do this. Thanks for input though

Answer (score 1):

[barrel](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/main-1/barrel) is the solution for you (For typescript).

For [javascript](https://srinivasankk.com/javascript-barrel/)

`Header.js` file has to be renamed as `index.js`